# Output from DifferentialEquations.jl at specific points

Tags: julia, differential-equations

I've trying to use DifferentialEquations.jl from Julia. I managed to get it working but I'd like know how to generate output at specific time points. The docs aren't clear on this and I've not found a single example that does this. The code I'm currently using is from the tutorial:

```
using DifferentialEquations
using Plots

function lorenz(du,u,p,t)
 du[1] = 10.0*(u[2]-u[1])
 du[2] = u[1]*(28.0-u[3]) - u[2]
 du[3] = u[1]*u[2] - (8/3)*u[3]
end

u0 = [1.0;0.0;0.0]
tspan = (0.0,100.0)
prob = ODEProblem(lorenz,u0,tspan)
sol = solve(prob)

plot(sol,vars=(1,2,3))
```

Currently it generates 1287 points, and I've no idea how it decides that. My question is what if I wanted to generate 20 points between the span 0 to 100?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The ODE tutorial section on "Controlling the Solvers"](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/tutorials/ode_example/#Controlling-the-Solvers) demonstrates using `saveat` for this purpose. The demonstration is:

```
sol = solve(prob,reltol=1e-6,saveat=0.1)
```

which will save at 0.0, 0.1, ... in your example. Right below that it is noted that:

> More generally, saveat can be any collection of time points to save at.

So for example, we can use save at to save only at t=30, 60, and 78 as follows:

```
sol = solve(prob,saveat=[30.0,60.0,78.0])
```

These examples should put you in the right direction. For more details, see [the Output Controls section of the documentation](https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/basics/common_solver_opts/#solver_options).

Comment: Updated links:
"The ODE tutorial section on Controlling the Solvers" -> https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/tutorials/ode_example/#Controlling-the-Solvers

"... the Output Controls section of the documentation" -> https://docs.sciml.ai/DiffEqDocs/stable/basics/common_solver_opts/#solver_options